# How to add multiple figures in a clear way in LateX

Tags: graphics, positioning

I am using TeXstudio.

There is a research paper that produces some figures like this:
[image]

When i replicate it, and produce the results, my graph looks like this:
[image]

Now, not only mine is hard to interpret, but it also takes up the whole page. Is there any way to make it fit the page adequately?

The code I am using is:

```
\documentclass[12pt]{article}
\usepackage{bm}
\usepackage{mathrsfs}
\usepackage{graphicx}
\usepackage{subfig}
\usepackage{adjustbox}
\usepackage{multirow}
\usepackage{caption}
\usepackage{rotating}
\usepackage{afterpage}
\usepackage{geometry}
\usepackage{fancyhdr}
\usepackage{float}
\usepackage{amsmath,amssymb,xcolor}

\newcommand\RED{\color{red}}

\newcommand{\tikzmark}[2]{\tikz[overlay,remember picture,baseline] \node[anchor=base] (#1) {$#2$};}
\renewcommand{\baselinestretch}{1.5}



\begin{document}
\maketitle
\afterpage{
    \thispagestyle{empty} 
    \newgeometry{left=1cm,right=1cm,top=1cm,bottom=1cm}

    \begin{figure}[ht]%
        \includegraphics[width=19.5cm]{limaols.png} %
        \renewcommand{\baselinestretch}{1.00}\normalsize\caption{STUFF}
    \end{figure}
    \restoregeometry
    \clearpage
}
\clearpage

\end{document}
```

Comment: Welxcome to TeX SX! Please post a full compilable code.

Comment: I am creating the graphs in R, then I insert them in Latex! You mean the latex Code that I use right?

Comment: Yes. If all graphs have the same size, could you post one?

Comment: All the graphs are automatically made into one in R `par(mfrow=c(3,5))`. They are the same size i am sure.

Comment: I don't know what `par(mfrow(3,5))`means. I suppose this is R syntax?

Comment: Yes, It automatically puts the graphs produced one next to another in 3 rows and 5 columns.

Comment: If you want the image to scale properly you should insert PDF not PNG and make sure `ggplot` (or whatever) scales the plot to the size you want. Second, when you only specify one parameter in `\includegraphics` you don't keep the aspect ratio, so add `keepaspectratio` to your `\includegraphics` command.

Comment: The problem is in limaols.png, not LaTeX.

Comment: I see! I used the version of `pdf` instead of `png` and I have to admit it is much better. Still not as cool as the original.

Answer (score 2):

I would suggest something like this:

```
\noindent
\begin{tikzpicture}

\foreach \j in {0,...,3}{
\foreach \i in {0,...,5}
{
\pgfmathsetmacro{\z}{int(\i+\j+1)}
\pgfmathsetmacro{\x}{\i*3}
\pgfmathsetmacro{\y}{-\j*3}
\node[below] at (\x,\y) {\includegraphics[width=2 cm,keepaspectratio]{myimage\z.png}};
}
}
\end{tikzpicture}
```

You have just to name the images with a number before the extension of the filename... Also if you decide to do something like this we can improve it to make separate figure in every page

Comment: This doesn't answer the question, I'm afraid. The image is a single image generated in R, not a bunch of individual small images.

Comment: Ok... I did not noticed from the beginning... The title made me to think of this situation...

I will leave my answer because with this title I am sure that my answer will help other people

Comment: I give +1 Because you can extract the Graphs one by one. It is more time consuming; yes. But that can work in a one by one manner.

Comment: Thanks... Creating the graphics one by one is a common way for R+latex and gives more choices and flexibility to the way we can use it in our document... The R code can very easily modified to give separated graphs